# Should NSUInteger enum properties be pointers or just primitives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, enums

I have the following `enum`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, GraphType) {
    GraphTypeRawData,
    GraphTypeFilteredData
};
```

The compiler accepts without warning me declaring it as a property primitive, or as a pointer:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) GraphType graphType;
```

VS

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) GraphType *graphType;
```

Which is the correct one to use? (And why?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a primitive type. Don't use a pointer unless you have a very clear and specific reason to track a pointer to a primitive type (which will be very rare).

Comment: Hi, could you please cite a scenario where a pointer to a primitive type might be needed and how would someone use it in such a case? I am just curious. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig I don't know of a case where you would want a property for a pointer to a primitive. I've never had the need for such a thing.